# How to run a java class only once in background, in a feature file

Tags: java, karate

I have a statement in the background of a feature file as,

```
def token = Java.type("Calling a static method from a java class")
```

I have 4 scenarios in my feature file and this java class is called 4 times. How to call this java class only once?

Comment: I do not know karate, but I would guess: when you dont want a method to be called 4 times, then you shouldnt have code doing that in 4 places. In other words: see if you can for example call that method **once**, to then *store*/cache that token value somehow, instead of fetching it again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to karate docs you have to use `callonce`

> Variables set using def in the Background will be re-set before every Scenario. If you are looking for a way to do something only once
>   per Feature, take a look at callonce. On the other hand, if you are
>   expecting a variable in the Background to be modified by one Scenario
>   so that later ones can see the updated value - that is not how you
>   should think of them, and you should combine your 'flow' into one
>   scenario. Keep in mind that you should be able to comment-out a
>   Scenario or skip some via tags without impacting any others. Note that
>   the parallel runner will run Scenario-s in parallel, which means they
>   can run in any order.

Please check

- https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure
- https://github.com/intuit/karate#callonce
- https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callonce/call-once.feature

Comment: I guess callonce is used to call a feature or any other file. My requirement here is to call a java file. So we need Java.type to call it.

Comment: call and callonce can execute features or JavaScript functions. Check the example about how to invoke a Java class, even static methods from JavaScript. Then once you have wrapped the Java class into a JavaScript function, use callonce to execute it only one time.
https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

Answer (score 0):

Background:

- karate.callSingle('called.feature@scenarioToBeCalledOnceInBackground');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31036575)